# Need Query form to extract Min and Max DateList values for PlotRange from a Dataset

Tags: dataset

(* SUMMARY - In a Dataset holding DateList entries, how do I extract a minimum and maximum DateList value to pass into DateListPlot's PlotRange specification?  See QUESTION further below *)

(* Sample dataset.  Actual dataset is much larger.  My goal is to create a time series animation where the PlotRange has fixed dimensions for the X/Y axis *)

```
aDataSet =Dataset[{
<|"aDate"-> { 2015,4,3,2,36,"24." },"aDuration"->5|>,
<|"aDate"-> { 2014,3,2,1,36,"24." },"aDuration"->4|>,
<|"aDate"-> { 2013,2,2,0,36,"24." },"aDuration"->3|>
}];
```

(* PlotRange for aData *)

```
dateRange=Sort[aDataSet[[All,"aDate"]]]/@ {First,Last};
```

(* PlotRange for duration *)

```
durationRange = Sort[aDataSet[[All,"aDuration"]]]/@ {First,Last};
```

(* QUESTION - how should I compute dateRange such that it is a form that can be used in PlotRange for DateListPlot?  Otherwise, the following will fail because the computed form of dateRange is a Dataset.  DateListPlot is expecting a List whose values are the min and maximum dates for the x-axis *)

```
DateListPlot[aDataSet[[All,{"aDate", "aDuration"}]],Joined->False,
    PlotRange->{dateRange,durationRange}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Thank you for taking a moment to re-formatting my inquiry to improve its readability!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your running into trouble with those `"24."` as the last entry in your date list.  That should be a number instead of a string.

```
aDataSet =Dataset[{
 <|"aDate"-> { 2015,4,3,2,36,24.},"aDuration"->5|>,
 <|"aDate"-> { 2014,3,2,1,36,24.},"aDuration"->4|>,
 <|"aDate"-> { 2013,2,2,0,36,24.},"aDuration"->3|>
}];
```

With it as a number then the following would work.

```
aDataSet[All, "aDate", DateObject][{Max, Min}] // Normal
```

It gets `All` of the `"aDate"` values and converts them into `DateObject`s.  The gets the `Min` and `Max` and takes it out of the dataset and into a regular list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: BINGO -- Thank you for catching the data typo ... but more importantly, your sample code here answered my issue -- thank you!

Comment: @AChaseTurner you can also use `MinMax` instead of `{Min, Max}`, if you have 10.1.

Comment: Thank you -- I am using 10.1 and MinMax works for me!